# Laravel 5.5 blade file not call

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

Controller File:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
   'type' => 'required|string|max:255',
]);

$type_data = new Type();
$type_detial = $type_data->add_type($request);

session()->flash('type_create', 'Type Created Successfully!');
return redirect('types/list');
```

Blade File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>List</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Web.php:

```
Route::resource('types', 'TypeController');
```

Insert data in Database than not redirect in list page. Error given is

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

I create a `list.blade.php` file.

Answer (score 3):

Please change `return redirect('types/list');` to `return view('list');`

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
                     'type' => 'required|string|max:255',
                 ]);

$type_data = new Type();
$type_detial = $type_data->add_type($request);

session()->flash('type_create', 'Type Created Successfully!');
return view('list');
```

OR

if you don't want to change anything in controller than
add this route in route file

```
Route::get('types/list', function(){
    return view('list');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
return redirect('types/');
and in controller 
public function index()
 {
     return view('types.list', compact('types'));
}
it's work for me.